# How to make nav expand when expanding nav items

Tags: html, jquery, css, bootstrap-4, navbar

I have a portfolio website with a few nav items for different views. I basically copied the default nav code from the bootstrap site. When I expand my "hamburger" the nav remains the same size, hence making the expanded items overlap with the border of my nav. Like this:

[image]

I can't seem to find anything on the Bootstrap site to deal with this issue. Does it have to do with my border being there?
Here's my nav code:

```css
.navbar{
    height: 10.0rem;
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(168, 168, 168);
}
.bg-light {
    background-color: white !important;
}
.navbar-collapse{
    padding-left: 0;
}

#options{
    list-style-position: inside;
    padding-left: 12rem;
}
#options li{
    padding-left: 1rem;
    padding-right: 1rem;
    font-size: 1.2rem;
    font-family: Raleway;
}
li a:hover{
    border-bottom: 0.001rem solid black;
}
.navbar-brand{
    font-size: 4rem;
    padding-left: 3rem;
    font-family: Raleway;
    font-weight: 400;
}
#header-container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row-reverse;
    justify-content: right;
    width: 50%;
    height: 50%;
    margin: 0 0 0 10%;
    padding-left: 30%;
}

html{
    height: fit-content;
}
body {
    padding-top: 5.0rem;
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Alan Alban - Portfolio</title>
</head>
  <body>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Alan Alban</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <section id="header-container">
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
        <ul class="navbar-nav" id="options">
          <li class="nav-item active">
            <a class="nav-link" href="/">Experience <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="/projects">Projects</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="/skills">Skills</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </section>
  </nav>
  
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

I appreciate the help in advance

Answer (score 0):

You are only importing the jquery.min.js but you should import the bootatrap.min.js too.

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-9/reFTGAW83EW2RDu2S0VKaIzap3H66lZH81PoYlFhbGU+6BZp6G7niu735Sk7lN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-w1Q4orYjBQndcko6MimVbzY0tgp4pWB4lZ7lr30WKz0vr/aWKhXdBNmNb5D92v7s" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

This is the full script you should place at the bottom of your body, just before the tag ends.

And move your css in your head tag.

Read the official documentation that will help you getting started, most of the answer are always there.

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/getting-started/introduction/

You can find there also good working examples that will help you getting started in a proper way.

Comment: I do have bootstrap, i just didn't copy it on this example but I do get bootstrap behavior. The only issue is that nav not expanding.

Comment: Ok, so if i didn't get it wrong you would like to put your navbar item list under that line border and increase the size of the text when hovered, is that right? First of all you shouldn't use a section in your navbar tag, instead you can add your class in the navbar div class. If you want to modify the text style i would suggest you to use the bootstrap styling, as i can see you would like to align your text on right, so just put a "text-right" in your class and for the text size if you want it bigger in hover then you could add it on your css under "li a:hover".

Comment: If you want to let the navbar expand under the line you could add a padding in the class of the tag "ul", still using bootstrap integrated styling for me in worked as a charm "pt-5". I hope i understood your problem right. If the nav is not expanding at all be sure your importing the jquery first and then the bootstrap.min.js.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out what the problem was.

```css
.navbar{
    height: 10.0rem;
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(168, 168, 168);
}
```

That snippet is how I intended to modify the initial width of my navbar. I removed the height property and it works fine now.

[image]

My guess is, by setting a height, I'm essentially anchoring the nav to a specific size. I'm gonna try min height and see if that works. it looks good as it is though since I have padding for my nav elements.